# изменение преребираемого foreach массива внутри цикла

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

```
$a = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');

foreach($a as $b){
    $i=0;
    if($b == 'two' || $b == 'four'){
        unset($a[$i]);
    }
    $i++;
}
if(count($a) == 0){
    print 'все значения найдены';
}
```

Правильно ли так делать? Если нет, то как правильнее сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У цикла `foreach` существует еще одна форма записи, позволяющая использовать в теле цикла еще и ключи массива. С ее использованием, ваш код может быть записан вот так:

```
$a = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');

foreach($a as $index => $val){
    if($val == 'two' || $val == 'four'){
        unset($a[$index]);
    }
}
```

Но правильнее в данном случае использовать функцию [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php):

```
$a = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');

$res = array_filter($a, function($item) {
    return ($item !== 'two' && $item !== 'four');
});
```

Comment: Массив набирается из данных взятых в бд, после перебирается циклом, в котором стоят условия поиска значений массива в строке, поэтому `array_filter` наверное не подойдет

Comment: @user193361, а какая разница? Как только у вас есть массив, вы можете использовать любой способ его фильтрации.

Comment: да, хорошее дополнение, пойду изучу подробнее

Answer (score 1):

foreach($a as &$b)
-позволит изменять $b внутри цикла. Вроде не применимо для php7

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
$a = array_diff($a, ['two', 'four']);
```